# Would a 'best of year' megapost be a good idea?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think there are many good questions that are overlooked because they were asked ages ago, and often times I even miss great questions that are posted now, because of my timezone.

Wouldn't it be good to showcase our best questions from each year?

The main objective is more to draw attention to undervalued questions, in addition to showcasing ones that have already been appreciated sufficiently.

The community could nominate questions in November/December and the list could be ready by the end of January.

Any ideas for implementation, or reasoning for or against this is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: superuser.com has (had?) something slightly similar they called "question of the week" where people would [nominate and vote on meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week) then the chosen would get a [blog post on their blog](http://blog.superuser.com/category/qotw/).

Comment: Also, since all SE content is Creative Commons, sometimes 3rd parties wolf up SE questions and answers and turn them into 'agony aunt' style articles ([examples](http://arstechnica.com/author/stack-exchange/)). There's definitely a time and a place for a bit of after-the-fact editorial.

Comment: Bounties also help do just that i.e. awareness, and a chance to have an answer if there is none because of the reward. Bounties can also reward existing Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

I'm against. How are you going to decide on best questions? By selecting the ones with the most upvotes? Then its for someone to already do that: [`Votes`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)

And where would we put this? In the Meta? New users generally don't look at Meta anyways.

And the undervalued one means we'd have to come to a community consensus about the best under-appreciated questions to showcase. We couldn't even come to a consensus to update the blurb...

This seems like a nice idea, but one that wouldn't be able to be executed at all.

---

User, if you want to then make a Community Promotion Ad for a particular Question you want to draw attention to. If others want to draw attention to it as well they can upvote it. If it gets 6 upvotes it will join the ad loop. That seems like a much simpler solution that doesn't involve meta posts and debate.

Comment: @user see my edit under the horizontal rule

Comment: @user there's nothing prohibiting it, Scott already created one for a particular question: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/959/2611

Comment: @user I don't agree, sorry. I don't see the point in yet another way to promote things when we already have methods that aren't in use. It currently has all of 1 upvotes in the community promotion. If it had the 6 threshold and still no answers then maybe I could see a purpose, but right now I'd rather see people promote with the existing tools then try to create new ones.